# error al desplegar WAR en weblogic server 12c

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

Tengo problemas al momento de desplegar un `war` a `weblogic`, es una aplicacion desarrollado con `java ee`,`framework spring` cuando compilo en netbeans y genera el `.war` al desplegarlo me lanza este error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use
>   InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
>
> Error Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.
>   See Spring documentation

Aparentemente hay una dependencia que no encuentra, pero en mi archivo `.pom` tengo todas las dependencias referentes a `spring`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>toplink.essentials</groupId>
        <artifactId>toplink-essentials</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-41b</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

No sé que podría estar haciendo mal, si alguien le ha pasado algo similar trabajando con el servidor de aplicaciones `weblogic` le agradezco su ayuda

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477889/exception-must-start-with-java-agent-to-use-instrumentationloadtimeweaver-see viene la posible solución -javaagent:C:\Users\whatever\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\3.2.5.RELEASE\spring-instrument-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

Comment: ya lo solucione amigo, la libreria si estaba en el repositorio y estaba en el POM solo faltaba una instruccion en el codigo que hiciera el llamado especificamente en el archivo XML

Comment: Puedes ponerlo como respuesta por favor, para que alguien más si le llega a pasar pueda solucionarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion es colocar en el archivo .xml servlet esta linea 
 
y listo el weblogic recononce dicha libreria